# Why use QueryClient.prefetchQuery instead of useQuery for caching in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-query, tanstackreact-query, fetching-strategy

Why should I use `QueryClient.prefetchQuery` instead of `useQuery` for caching in React-Query?

I don't see any valuable use case. If I want to prefetch, I could just use `useQuery` when the app is loaded without actually using the fetched values. When I use it somewhere else, I would get the cached result from the previous `useQuery`. At least this is how I see things.

But I think I'm missing something. Maybe SSR related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read [the docs on prefecthing](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/prefetching)? It can be used to fetch something *before* you render it so that you can see the data instantly once the user navigates to it. If you wait until `useQuery` tries to read the data, you will inevitably fetch later and thus see a loading spinner.

We also use prefetching in one of our examples: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/examples/react/prefetching

Comment: With the example, it's clearer, thanks. I was missing the use case for prefetching on event, that is obviously not possible with a hook.

Answer (score 1):

UseQuery is used when the component is mounted or simply when it is destructured from a view.

const { queryProblem, queryComments } = useIssue();

queryClient.prefetchQuery is used before mounting a component, to make a request with arbitrary code apart from a condition or event.

For example, you could execute a prefetchQuery when the OnMouseEnter event fires.

Answer (score 1):

A key difference between `prefetchQuery` and `useQuery` is that `useQuery` will re-execute (and so trigger a re-render) whenever the cache for its `queryKey` is invalidated, whereas `prefetchQuery` will not.

So if you have a *mounted* `useQuery` hook and you execute a mutation against its query key and use `invalidateQueries`, then the `useQuery` hook will re-render. However, the `prefetchQuery` would not re-render.

If you are literally just prefectching data then you do not want the fetch hook to repeatedly trigger a re-render later on whenever its cache is invalidated, and this is the use case for `prefetchQuery`.

So although `prefetchQuery` may seem to perform the same function as `useQuery` it should be the preferred option for prefetching.